# dc.js chart with Square, Line and Triangle

Tags: dc.js

I have a requirement to build the chart shown below:

[image]

I'm not sure about the name of the graph. But the structure of the graph should be like this.
It contains horizontal line with square at the end and up and down triangles.
Each of these shape indicated different categories. Hence it should be shown in different color.

Up triangle indicated a category which is higher than upper limit.

Down triangle indicated a category which is lower than lower limit.

Horizontal line with square indicates a category 'Event' and its length denotes no. of days for the Event.

Comment: Sorry but I don’t think dc.js offers any charts which could be easily modified to produce this. The closest is the scatter plot, but you’d have to add the lines and it doesn’t have the concept of intervals with start and end time. I guess your best bet is to find a D3 example that does what you need and then adapt it for dc.js.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.